# How can I inject environment variables during the build process in Github CI/CD?

Tags: environment-variables, gatsby, github-actions, contentful

I am creating a blogsite with Gatsby and Contentful for learning purposes. I want to deploy my site to surge using Github actions. I am using `gatsby-source-contentful` plugin to get my content from Contentful at build time. The plugin requires `spaceId` and `accessToken` to access my Contenful space. During development at my local machine, I am providing these values to the plugin using environment variables saved in a `.env` file.

However, during the build process in Github actions, I am getting this error:

```
success open and validate gatsby-configs - 2.325s
error Invalid plugin options for "gatsby-source-contentful":

- "accessToken" is required
- "spaceId" is required
not finished load plugins - 1.002s
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gatsby-contentful-blogsite@0.1.0 build: `tsc && gatsby build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-contentful-blogsite@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-02-18T17_53_11_281Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Is there a way to tell Github actions about these environment variables (`spaceId` and `accessToken`) so that the `gatsby-source-contentful` plugin can be configured successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contentful DevRel here.

```
// In your gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
      options: {
        spaceId: `your_space_id`,
        // Learn about environment variables: https://gatsby.dev/env-vars
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

In your gatsby config you can specify your environment variable such as above. Then in your GitHub repo you can define a secret and expose it as environment variable. You can find more information in [the Github actions docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow). Once you exposed the environment variable via the secret to the action, it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much: it worked. I tried very hard to find something relevant in the Github Docs before posting this question. But I couldn't find this page. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help. :) It'd be great if you could mark the questions as answered then. :)